# Objective C To Swift Issue

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have been trying for ages to try an convert this Objective-C into Swift but with no success! Any ideas?

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:recognizer.view.tag];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
let button = view.viewWithTag(recognizer.view!.tag) as UIButton
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Rob! Worked A Treat ^_____^

Comment: Please tick the checkmark next to the answer when you have accepted it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: BTW, @JoshRobbins, it's a little curious to get the view's tag and then use that tag to get the view. Do you really have two different views that happen to have the same tag in different containers? If not, you might be able to streamline this further.